# React router 4 react-router-config prevent components from unmounting

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using the `renderRoutes()` function from `react-router-config` in my isomorphic react app.  I have a situation where there are many endpoints for the same component.  Each time the user navigates to a new endpoint I need to fetch data for that endpoint and render it to the component.  Typically i would do this via `componentWillReceiveProps()`, and then fire an AJAX request based upon the new URL.  However every time I navigate to a different endpoint the component is unmounted and remounted.  Is there a way to prevent the component being unmounted and just have it's properties updated?

```
export const routes = [
{
    component: SectionFront,
    path: '/' ,
    exact: true,
    loadData: ( match ) =>{      
    return loadSectionFront( match.path )
    },
    },{
    component: SectionFront,
    path: '/investing' ,
    exact: false,
    loadData: ( match ) =>{
    return loadSectionFront( match.path )
    }
},
{
    component: SectionFront,
    path: '/news/companies' ,
    exact: false,
    loadData: ( match ) =>{
    return loadSectionFront( match.path )
    }
}]

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <CoreLayout>
            {renderRoutes(routes)}
          </CoreLayout>
        </BrowserRouter>
     </Provider>,
    mountNode
  );
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is related to `react-router-config` itself. According to the source code of its [renderRoutes routine](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-config/modules/renderRoutes.js#L5) it will always render only one `Route` because of `Switch` component wrapping passed routes.

I think you'll have to come with your own solution for create-routes-from-config approach.